# Bluetooth Client Server

Tags: android

I am trying to create a Server and a Client with Bluetooth. 
My idea is the Server app sends a message to Client app with Bluetooth. 
I am testing both apps on the same smartphone. 
Unfortunately I can't make it work.

Client:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  TextView tv1,tv2;
  BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
  BluetoothServerSocket mBluetoothServerSocket;
  InputStream mInputStream;
  BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;
  BufferedReader mBufferedReader;
  String data;
  UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mBluetoothAdapter= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    try {
        mBluetoothServerSocket=mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Service Name",MY_UUID);
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        mBluetoothSocket=mBluetoothServerSocket.accept();
        mInputStream=mBluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
        if(mInputStream.available()>0){
            data=mBufferedReader.readLine();
            tv2.setText(data);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Server:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
private Button lb;
private BluetoothDevice device;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket;
private OutputStream outStream;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice("00:03:AB:59:19:C3");
    try {
        btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        btSocket.connect();
        String message = "Message\n";
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    lb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String m1 = "msg 2";
            byte[] msgBuffer = m1.getBytes();
            try {
                outStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You better use two devices to  begin with.

Comment: The client app doesn't open and the server app stop working when I press the button.

Comment: What can we do with that info do you think? Nothing!